# Spring Websocket not working with ssl (wss)

Tags: angular, spring, sockets, stomp, sockjs

I have an application with a websocket connection between a Spring backend and an Angular Frontend behind a Spring Cloud Gateway which works perfectly via http / ws but doesn't work at all.

What I tried and what worked:

- starting the angular frontend and spring backend directly
- starting the angular frontend and the spring backend locally with docker behind a local spring cloud gateway
- exposing a port directly on the backend docker container (emitting the gateway which usses ssl on the server) and starting the angular frontend locally against that backend (with angular proxy)

What does not work:

- starting the backend with a docker container and using the websocket with https/wss

I configured the spring cloud gateway as described here https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-gateway/reference/html/:

```
    - id: websocketinfo
      uri: http://app
      predicates:
        - Host=app.domain.com
        - Path=/api/ws/info/**
    - id: websocket
      uri: ws://app
      predicates:
        - Host=app.domain.com
        - Path=/api/ws/**
```

The only difference between my local gateway (with which the websocket communication works) and the server gateway is that I have ssl enabled on the server with a p12 key

The error message that I get in the spring cloud gateway is:

```
io.netty.handler.codec.http.websocketx.WebSocketHandshakeException: Invalid handshake response getStatus: 403
```

In the Spring Backend Service I get these errors a lot:

```
2020-04-09 07:03:55.298  WARN 1 --- [p-nio-80-exec-4] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException: No converter for [class java.util.LinkedHashMap] with preset Content-Type 'application/javascript;charset=UTF-8']
```

This confuses me a lot since that seems like the kind of error that should happen no matter which environment you run the application in

Answer (score 1):

So apparently this was a bug with an older version of spring cloud gateway. After updating to spring version 2.2.1 everything worked with ssl too